# Run javascript after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

setup_account ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c

When a page i make loads like this:

```
var location    =   location.href+"&rndm="+2*Math.random()+" #updatecomment0>*"
$("#updatecomment0").load(location, function(){});
```

I have multiple scripts running on the `updatecomment0` `div`:

```
<div id="updatecomment0">
    <div id="javascript1">hi</div>
    <div style="float:right;" class="javascript2">delete</div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to make this other JavaScripts run *after* page load.
Can someone please tell me how to with this.
Thank you

Comment: Use the callback function of `.load`.

Comment: Why is everything in boldface? We can read normal font weights too ;)

Answer (score 12):

[Use](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Will this work even when the content is loaded after the main page?

Comment: How are you loading the new content?

Comment: Let's suppose the content is loaded using the `onClick` event of some element. Will this work?

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is. `$(document).ready(handlerFunction)` will simply execute the `handlerFunction` when the document is loaded. If you want something to happen to the content loaded using `onClick`, you can just specify that in the `onClick` handler.

Comment: i use this before $(document).ready() but it not working. the sample layout above, i try with a simple javascript .hide div after .load and it works. thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery, you can do this very easily.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Your DOM is ready.Now below this u can run all ur javascript');
});
```

Comment: yes, i try . i dont know the different between $(document).ready(function(){ with jQuery(document).ready(function(){ . but i will try it again

Comment: there is not difference. `$` is just a alias of `jQuery`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample layout for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /// here you can put all the code that you want to run after page load
        function Javascript1(){
            //code here
        }

        function Javascript2(){
            // code here
        }

        $("#btnOK").live('click',function(){
            // some codes here
            Javascript1();
            Javascript2();
        });

    });
</script>

<div id="MyDiv">
    <input type="button" id="btnOK" value="OK"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @Benyamin please mark this post as the answer or whichever answer that you think solved your problem. thank you! :D

Answer (score 2):

write code inside `ready`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

// write here
});
```

suggestion : use `live` or `bind`

Comment: yes, i change $(document).ready(function(){ to jQuery(document).ready(function(){

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need javascript to do something before the page is loaded, add your scripts to the bottom om the html document, just before the **body** end tag. 
The page will load faster, and you can do whatever you need to, right in the js file, without the document ready functions.

If the scripts is the last to load, the DOM is already guaranteed to be "ready".

Comment: yes, some of the javascript i need to do something before the page is loaded. i try jQuery(document).ready(function(){ and with .live sample layout and so far is good

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: I needed to resize some elements based on the height of another. This worked for me if you're trying something similar.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready()` is all you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make JavaScript wait for a specified time using the `setTimeout` method:

```
.setTimeout("name_of_function()",time_in_millis);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you too, I had a similar issue and I fixed it by calling the following just after loading the content in the page (like after an AJAX request for a page to be shown inside a div):

```
(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // your pretty function call, or generic code
 });
}(jQuery));
```

**Remember to not call this in the document you load, but in the function that load it, after it as been loaded.**

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla Javascript, this can done thusly:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

// other javascript here

function onAfterLoad() { /*...*/ }

// other javascript here

</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- HTML content here -->

<!-- onAfterLoad event handling -->
<div style="display:none;"><iframe onload="onAfterLoad();"></iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```